# How do I program the following contingency?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I have an array with names of pets and another parallel array with the names of the sounds they make. I'm writing a method `ShowSounds()` which asks user for an animal name, and then displays the respective sound.

How do I code in an error message that says *"Sorry that animal isn't in our list"* if the user enters something random?

The problem I have right now is that with the `if` statement, it displays the error message four times even if I enter the correct animal.

```cs
public static void ShowSound(string userInput2, string[] localPets4, string[] localSounds2)
{
    for (int l = 0; l < localPets4.Length; l++)
    {
        if (userInput2 == localPets4[l])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} makes the sound {1}", localPets4[l], localSounds2[l]);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry that item isn't in our list of animals");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `else` branch needs to be outside of your `for` loop. You'll only know that the item isn't in your list after you've checked all its elements.

Comment: How would I format that? If I add the `else` outside the for loop then it doesn't pair with the `if` statement

Comment: You should also use `break` to leave the loop once you find a match.

Comment: @shanko just the branch, without the `else` keyword

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void ShowSound(string userInput2, string[] localPets4, string[] localSounds2)
{
    var result =
        localPets4
            .Zip(localSounds2, (pet, sound) => new { pet, sound })
            .Where(x => x.pet == userInput2)
            .FirstOrDefault();

    if (result != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{result.pet} makes the sound {result.sound}");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Sorry, {userInput2} isn't in our list of animals");
    }
}
```

The line `localPets4.Zip(localSounds2, (pet, sound) => new { pet, sound })` is matching element for element in the `localPets4` and `localSounds2` arrays and creates a single enumerable in the form of `new { pet, sound }`.

The `.Where(x => x.pet == userInput2)` only retains the elements where `pet` equals the `userInput2`.

This should mean that if there's a match then there's only one match and if there isn't a match then the enumerable is empty. Calling `.FirstOrDefault()` then either you have the single `new { pet, sound }` that manages the input or you have `null`.

The rest of the code simply produces the output based on the `result`.

Comment: Hmmm...well, I can't fault you for the _correctness_ of the code. :) But, it's a little fancy given the context. The OP almost certainly is writing this in the context of some educational setting, whether a class or their own independent learning. I feel like you added a 1200cc engine to the bike they just got the training wheels taken off of. Maybe just showing them the `Array.IndexOf<T>()` method would've been more their speed? That said, the _explanation_ is excellent, even if not necessarily useful to the author of _this_ question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use 
`Array.Exists(localPets4, x => x.Equals(userInput2));` 
to check if the input is valid, then if it is loop through to find the sound.

```
if (Array.Exists(localPets4, x => x.Equals(userInput2))) {
    for (int l = 0; l < localPets4.Length; l++)
    {
        if (localPets4[l].Equals(userInput2) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} makes the sound {1}", localPets4[l], localSounds2[l]);
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;
        }
    }
}
else
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Sorry that item isn't in our list of animals");
    }
```

But this will only check if the unserInput2 is an exact match. If you need approximate matches, then you'll have to get a little more elaborate.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I just caught that. It has been edited.

Comment: If you don't need the loop for anything else, then I agree with @Engimativity. But again, if you need more approximate matches you'll have to get creative.

Comment: [`Array.IndexOf<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_IndexOf__1___0_____0_System_Int32_) would be a much more direct way to go about it. It does the search and returns the exact index in a single call, no extra looping needed.

Comment: @Peter Duniho, I agree and thank you for the comment. But as you said to Enigmativity, I felt that this was a question geared for some educational venture. I wasn't sure if the loop was required for some reason, which the IndexOf() method would help to eliminate.

Comment: Sure, but your answer doesn't really fit the "educational context" anyway, so I figured you might as well be efficient about it. :) (And if you're wondering what I mean about the "educational context", your answer changes the overall structure of the code significantly, and not even in a desirable way -- it forces two scans of the array instead of just one...there are two other answers that stay much closer to the original, preserving its original structure while still only scanning through the array once.)

Comment: @Peter Duniho, I see what you are saying. Thank you. This isn't really how I would have gone about this, I was trying to stay somewhat close to the original context. But you are right... To be honest, what I have learned here is to ask more questions of the OP's intent before I try to answer. This would lead to less sloppy answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to print that statement once (if no items are found), it needs to be removed from the loop:

```
public static void ShowSound(string userInput2, string[] localPets4, string[] localSounds2) 
{ 
    bool itemFound = false;

    for (int l = 0; l < localPets4.Length; l++) 
    { 
        if (userInput2 == localPets4[l])
        { 
            itemFound = true;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} makes the sound {1}", localPets4[l], localSounds2[l]);
            Console.WriteLine(); 
        }
    } 

    if (!itemFound)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry that item isn't in our list of animals"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is related to the traversing of your array. If `string[] localPets4` contains 4 elements, your `for loop` will iterate 4 times - ergo 4 error messages.
Therefor in your for loop you should only do the search. Then the logic to feedback the user - on success/failure - will be handled outside the `for loop`.

```
int foundAtIndex = -1;

for (int l = 0; l < localPets4.Length; l++) 
{ 
    if (userInput2 == localPets4[l])
    { 
        foundAtIndex = l;
    }
}
if (foundAtIndex != -1)
{
        Console.WriteLine("{0} makes the sound {1}", localPets4[foundAtIndex ],localSounds2[foundAtIndex ]);
        Console.WriteLine(); 
}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Sorry, {userInput2} isn't in our list of animals");
    Console.WriteLine(); 
}
```

As this is a 1-To-1 relationship you could use a `[Dictionary][1]` , but I am not sure whether this is out of the scope of your application.